# "readonly if parameter" is not working in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

If the current url have the parameter "action=edit" I want some controls marked as readonly.

I've tried the following:

URL: http://x.x.x.x:8080/department?id=000001&action=edit

```
<input type="text" th:placeholder="#{department.id}" class="form-control" th:field="*{id}" th:readonly="${param.action == 'edit'}">
```

This is always false for some reason. I've also tried showing the value:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" th:value="${param.action}" th:readonly="${param.action=='edit'}">
```

This show the value 'edit' in the input but readonly is still false. Then I tried the following: "${param.action **!=** 'edit'}" and this is working. Why? param.action is equal to 'edit' but that IF is taking some different value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`${param.action}` is an array (in order to support multivalued parameters).](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#web-context-namespaces-for-requestsession-attributes-etc.) In order to get the value, you'll probably have to do something like this:

```
${param.action != null AND param.action[0]=='edit'}
```

(You can skip the null check if the action parameter will always appear, otherwise you'll run into null pointer exceptions.)